# Display None Issue

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, media-queries

I am very new to web design, and this is the 2nd website I have designed my site that meets the requirements of my assessment, I cannot get my Nav bar to disappear. I have "Other Pages"  which I would like to appear when below 600px and disappear above that, my ul navbar should be present when above 600px and disappear when below.

Sorry for the eye damage.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="html/aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="html/menu.html">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="html/zoo.html">Zoo</a></li>
<li><a href="html/parksandwalks.html">Parks and Walks</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Other Pages
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="../sunshine/html/aboutus.html">About Us</a>
      <a href="../sunshine/html/menu.html">Menu</a>
      <a href="../sunshine/html/zoo.html">Zoo</a>
      <a href="../sunshine/html/parksandwalks.html">Parks and Walks</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #0099cc;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    [class*="col-6"] {
    width: 100%;
          }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    li a {width: 100%}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    li a {text-align: center;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    li {width: 100%}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  
@media only screen and (max-width: 60px) {
  div.navbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
    
@media only screen and (max-width: 60px) {
  div.links {
    display: none;
  }
}   
    
    .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

/* Navbar container */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

I apologise for the eye damage I have inflicted with this, yes, I copied most of this from W3Schools.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] (emphasis on the *minimal*).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
ul {
  display:none;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .navbar{display:none;}
  ul{display:flex}
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="html/aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="html/menu.html">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="html/zoo.html">Zoo</a></li>
      <li><a href="html/parksandwalks.html">Parks and Walks</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Other Pages
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="../sunshine/html/aboutus.html">About Us</a>
      <a href="../sunshine/html/menu.html">Menu</a>
      <a href="../sunshine/html/zoo.html">Zoo</a>
      <a href="../sunshine/html/parksandwalks.html">Parks and Walks</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```